# Custom field validation in system.xml

Tags: magento2, validation, system.xml

I'm developing the magento2 plugin(I'm kinda new in magento2), and I ran into a problem with validation the field in system.xml. I've been searching for a long time and did not find the answer. I added a new field but I need to validate this field using the regex. I saw that there is a some default validation but I need custom one, is there any way to add a new validation rule to validator?

Comment: which type of validation you need to put on this?

Comment: Magento 2 [Custom validation rules](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/validations/custom-validation.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to register your custom validation method and then use it for your field in `system.xml` file.

Define your validation method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "validate-custom", 
    function (v) {
        return jQuery.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(v) || /^[1-4]+$/.test(v);
     },
    'Please use digits only (1-4) in this field.'
);
```

And use it for your field in `system.xml`:

```
<validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater validate-custom</validate>
```

Search for "validator.addMethod" in the Magento 2 core code, there are a bunch of examples there showing more complex use cases.

Comment: I try using this way but not working  
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262645/magento-2-2-3-how-to-change-validation-message-or-add-new-custom-rule-in-system

Answer (score 15):

As @Wojtek Naruniec writes, you have to create your own custom validation method in a javascript file and use it in your module configuration field in **system.xml** file.

Suppose your field as:

```
<field id="color" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Color</label>
    <comment>Exadecimal value, without #: ex. FFFFFF</comment>
</field>
```

and you would like to check field length (exactly 6 characters).

Create your javascript file,

> vendorName/moduleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/validation.js

for example:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/validate'],
    function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-exadecimal-color-length', function (v) {
                return (v.length == 6);
            }, $.mage.__('Field must have length of 6'));
    }
);
```

then load javascript file in admin configuration page so you have to generate the file

> vendorName/moduleName/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="vendorName_moduleName::js/validation.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Now you can use your validator adding `<validate>` tag into `<field>` tag of your **system.xml** file:

```
<field id="color" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Color</label>
    <validate>validate-exadecimal-color-length</validate>
    <comment>Exadecimal value, without #: ex. FFFFFF</comment>
</field>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much more thorough.

Comment: yes it should be