# Magento 2: Custom validation for system.xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, form-validation, system.xml, system-config

Is it possible to create a custom validation for fields in configuration? (**Stores > Settings > configuration**)

I created a `system.xml` file but the default values for the validate tag are not enough for my needs and I would like to create my own rules.

I found an other [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139023/custom-field-validation-in-system-xml/157296#157296) about this but it doesn't say how and where I should put/declare the validation method.

Is this possible or is the only solution to create **a backend model with a beforeSave** function?

Comment: To your question on how/where put the code for http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139023/custom-field-validation-in-system-xml/157296#157296 : You have to create a custom js file and then add js code in it. Then include that file in your code.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if we want to add more custom validations. We should validate with `beforeSave()`. For example, take a look the cookie validation:
`vendor/magento/module-cookie/Model/Config/Backend/Lifetime.php`.

We can add more Js validation for the user interface input.

A Sample to add Js validation for system xml:

In your module, create file the layout - `adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml`

[image]

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="js">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" 
                   template="Module_Vendor::system/config/custom_js.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Remember to add your custom validation in the template.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the beforesave function in a backend model to validate my fields. But your solution seems